# Why is grep() not working after readLines()?

Tags: r, readlines

I developed a program in R to read a report available online and the first 2 lines are:

```
page1 <- readLines("http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta/2013_2014/Modulo_AM/UC03-LeisOrc-RL&municipioSelecionado=3100203&exercicioSelecionado=2014")
line1 <- grep("Leis Autorizativas",page1)
```

The rest of the program worked fine and I got the data I needed. Then I tried to adapt it to read a different report, but this time the second line didn't work:

```
page2 <- readLines("http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta/2013_2014/Modulo_AM/UC08-ConsultarDecretos-RL&municipioSelecionado=3101607&exercicioSelecionado=2013")
line2 <- grep("Decretos de Alterações",page2)
```

In the 1st case 'page1' is a character vector and in the 2nd case 'page2' is a *large* character vector. Is it possible that this difference caused the problem? If so, does anybody have a hint on how to fix it?

(Using htmltab() or readHTMLtable() didn't produce good results)

Thank you.

Comment: The links you showed cannot be open on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "Decretos de Alterações" is not fully composed of ascii characters.

If you try with

```
page2 <- readLines("http://reportviewer.tce.mg.gov.br/default.aspx?server=noruega&relatorio=SICOM_Consulta/2013_2014/Modulo_AM/UC08-ConsultarDecretos-RL&municipioSelecionado=3101607&exercicioSelecionado=2013")

grep("Decretos de Altera&#231;&#245;es ", page2)

[1] 366
```

It works.

To know what number to put for replacement:

```
utf8ToInt("ç")
[1] 231
```

Then put the resulting number between `&` and `;`, and replace your non ascii letters.

Best

Colin